# How do I display a coloured drop down selector with HTML 5 and CSS 3?

Tags: html, css

I have a basic html select:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Banana</option>
    <option value="3">Grape</option>
</option>
```

I want to set the background colour of each option to a different one.  For instance, Apple is red, Banana is yellow and Grape is purple.  By initiating a drop down, I will see the different colours in each option.

Is it possible to achieve the above with CSS3/HTML5 on the latest **Firefox** and **Webkit**(Chrome and Safari) browsers?

**NOTE**: Can you test your solutions on both the latest Firefox and Chrome, possibly on the Mac?  I'm aware of the background colour method but it only works in Firefox on the Mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it not just as easy as this? http://jsfiddle.net/d8p8Q/

```html
<select>
    <option value="1" style="background:red">Apple</option>
    <option value="2" style="background:yellow">Banana</option>
    <option value="3" style="background:purple">Grape</option>
</select>
```

Am I missing something here?

[image] **Safari**           [image] **Chrome**           *(and I'm using Windows 7)*

"Grape" is blue because that's the one I'm hovering over. I don't think it's possible to change that blue "selected" colour using the native `<select>` element.

If that's what you're after doing, you'll have to swap out the `<select>`s with JavaScript replacements, such as these:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Comment: Yes, I added screenshots. What operating system are you using?

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, I don't see the colours on the latest Chrome on the Mac.

Comment: That's because WebKit browsers on Macs use the native operating system dropdown to render `<select>`s. See: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/select/. There is *no way* to change that, besides using JavaScript to swap them out, as in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
/* Style */
select option[value="1"] {
  background-color: #f00;  
}

select option[value="2"] {
  background-color: #0f0;   
}

select option[value="3"] {
  background-color: #00f;  
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<select>    
    <option value="1">Red</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
    <option value="3">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Of course it would be easier to target with classes, but this should get you started.

Comment: Does the above work in the latest Safari or Chrome?  I can't see the colours from my end in the latest Chrome.

Comment: @Thierry Just checked, looks fine in Chrome 12 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3HWUw/1/

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option id="one" value="1">Apple</option>
    <option id="two" value="2">Banana</option>
    <option id="three"value="3">Grape</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
#one {
    background-color: red;
}
#two {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#three {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above works, or you can do it in CSS like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JmwJ9/

Comment: For me (Chrome 76 on macOS 10.14.5) this is not working, I see a dropdown with no formatting: https://i.imgur.com/9hhpjlD.png